# Creation_date for index in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-5

I have added the index creation date in my index setting as 
below

```
"settings" :{ 
  "index" :{ 
     "provided_name":"test",
     "creation_Date":"1493750591836",
     "number_of_shards" : "1",
     "number_of_replicas" : "0"
  }
 }
```

But when i try to post the _template am getting error as below

```
  "unknown setting [index.creation_date] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings"
```

Does it means the creation time setting is not available, could any please clarify.  Am not able to find more details on this in
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/indices-update-settings.html

*The version used is 5.1*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not allowed to set that setting, only read it. However, what you can do is to use the `mappings._meta` section for that in order to store your custom index creation date:

```
PUT my_index
{
  "settings" :{ 
   "index" :{ 
     "number_of_shards" : "1",
     "number_of_replicas" : "0"
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "test": {
      "_meta": { 
        "creation_date":"1493750591836"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the info. How about provided_name & version of index , if am using a template how the index will know it should follow the  template.  Is there way i specify the template which it should refer at the time of index creation ?

Comment: In the template there is a property called "template" which should capture the index name. If the index you're creating matches that template name, then the template will be applied.

Comment: Thanks val that clarifies things.